# The receptive field of feature maps in CNN is overlapped. How does this affect?

Tags: conv-neural-network, feature-detection

The receptive field of a feature map in a convolutional neural network is repeated.What is the impact of such repeated calculations?Some people say that this is a repeated calculation for the original graph？ How to understand it？I know this may be a bit stupid，I hope everyone can show your opinion. thanks 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4LTX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, If i understand your question correct,then ,The impact of such multiple calculations is learning better/deeper features.The receptive field is just what portion of the image covered.The larger the receptive field more insight about the whole image context can be gained.And doing this repeatedly helps the network learn abstract/core features about the nature of the images you train them with.

Hope this helps.